# Adding abstraction layer in a direct Database Connection ADOdb (vba) <-> Oracle 19c DB

Tags: vba, oracle, adodb

i need to abstract a direct database connection because the current direct connection will not be possible anymore. We need to proxy the sql queries over a Kafka message broker.

**Currently we have the following:**

Client Application (VBA6.0) which uses ADOdb for a direct Connection to a remote Oracle 19c Database using MSAORA provider.

So:

```
vba6 --> adodb --> network --> oracle db
```

**The idea is this abstraction layer:**

```
vba6 --> adodb --> <custom middleware> --> Kafka --> microservice --> oracle db
```

The aim is to not or barely touch the vba/adodb part since it would be a huge workload.
The vba-script should not see any difference talking to the database or our proxy middleware.

Whats the best approach to archive this?
Is it possible to build a custom ODBC implementation (or something else) which then handles the SQL Queries by sending them over Kafka to a Microservice which then executes the query and sends the results back?